# Get the last classname of an array with jquery

Tags: jquery, split, classname

i want get the last item of an array with class names. My code looks like this

```
var getClassName = [];
getClassName = $(this).attr('class').split();
console.log(getClassName);
```

In the console i <s>become</s> get this answer

```
["classname1 classname2"]
```

how can i get the last class name?

Thanks

Comment: None of your five other questions has received an acceptable answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As jensgram points out, you're nearly there; see his answer for the detail if you want to stay jQuery-specific.

But you're making the browser do a lot of extra work, this is one of those times you really don't need jQuery:

```
var getClassName;
getClassName = this.className.split(' ');
console.log(getClassName[getClassName.length-1]);
```

The [`className` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-95362176) of DOM elements is supported by all major browsers (and probably all minor ones).

Still, unless you're doing this in a tight loop, the extra overhead of the `$()` and `attr` calls probably doesn't really matter much.

Comment: @jensgram: Wow, I saw and fixed that almost instantly, talk about timing. :-)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder And I took the liberty to change my gender :)

Comment: @jensgram: Thanks. You're going to laugh, but I read "jensgram" as "Jen's gram" as in "Jen's grandmother" and didn't apply my probability filter. :-) And I'm sure we have a couple of grandmothers here on SO, but I'm thinking not that many (probably more grandfathers).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder :) In this case it's `CONCAT(<firstName>, <lastName>)`, though.

Comment: @jens Hehe, it's not actually the first time @T.J. has got gender wrong! Hilarious comments :)

Answer (score 4):

```
console.log(getClassName[getClassName.length-1]);
```

[Will do](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/nsg8W/), *but* you need to pass an argument to `split()`:

```
var getClassName = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
var lastIndex = getClassName.length - 1;
console.log(getClassName[lastIndex]);
```

---

**EDIT: On using `this.className`**
Consider using `this.className` instead of `$(this).attr('class')`. This is mentioned in [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243984/get-the-last-classname-of-an-array-with-jquery/4244022#4244022).

[Andy E](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94197/andy-e) has done a great write-up on how we tend to overuse jQuery: [*Utilizing the awesome power of jQuery to access properties of an element*](http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/10/utilizing-the-awesome-power-of-jquery-to-access-properties-of-an-element). The article specifically treats the use of `.attr("id")` but the issue is the same for `$(...).attr('className')` vs. `this.className`.

You *could* even use

```
var getClassName = (this.className || '').split(' ');
```

if you're not sure that `.className` exists.

Comment: @Peter You should really follow @T.J. Crowder's advice and use `this.className` instead of the `.attr()`. I've just made this point in [another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243554/jquery-if-checkbox-is-checked-do-this/4243575#4243575).

Comment: @Stefan Mai Sort of. `var getClassName = "classname1 classname2".split(); alert(getClassName);` showed that `split()` would *not* use a whitespace as default split char. After editing it was obvious that I was not the only one to find out :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).attr('class').split(' ').pop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Note the documentation for split:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

You need to write:

```
split(' ')
```

Without the separator "the entire string will be returned"