# regular expression in Crockford's String.supplant

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to create a function like Douglas Crockford's String.supplant:

```
if (typeof String.prototype.supplant !== 'function') {
    String.prototype.supplant = function (o) {
        return this.replace(/{([^{}]*)}/g, function (a, b) {
            var r = o[b];
            return typeof r === 'string' ? r : a;
        });
    };
}
```

what it does is:

```
var html = '<div>{title}<h3>{time}</h3><p>{content}</p></div>';
var object = {title: "my title", time: "12h00m", content:"blablabla"}
supplanted = html.supplant(object);
//supplanted returns:
//<div>my title<h3>12h00m</h3><p>blablabla</p></div>
```

i need, for a project for my tags to be different: instead of `{tagname}`, i need it to be `[ns:tagname]`

does anyone here have enough knowledge of regular expressions to help me out?
thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following works:

```
if (typeof String.prototype.supplant !== 'function') {
    String.prototype.supplant = function (o) {
        return this.replace(/\[ns:([^\[\]]*)\]/g, function (a, b) {
            var r = o[b];
            return typeof r === 'string' ? r : a;
        });
    };
}
```

Do note, that the brackets are escaped (e.g., `[]` becomes `\[\]`) since they have a special meaning in regular expressions.

Example:

```
var html = '<div>[ns:title]<h3>[ns:time]</h3><p>[ns:content]</p></div>';
var object = {title: "my title", time: "12h00m", content:"blablabla"}
supplanted = html.supplant(object);
// "<div>my title<h3>12h00m</h3><p>blablabla</p></div>"
```

Comment: @André Alçada Padez You're welcome. BTW: I'm a male — name is Jens Gram. I'm not [Jen's grandmother](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243984/get-the-last-classname-of-an-array-with-jquery/4244022#4244022) :)

Comment: @André Alçada Padez No, I mixed up the comments. I was refering to "... as *she* was 2 minutes ..." in your comment to pimvdb.

Comment: I have a quick question, what are a,b in the inner function? Where do they come from?

Comment: @zer0c00l `a` and `b` are just the parameter names that I used for the first and second arguments in the anonymous replace function. A complete list is available at [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

Answer (score 2):

The regexp would need to be changed.

```
if (typeof String.prototype.supplant !== 'function') {
    String.prototype.supplant = function (o) {
        return this.replace(/\[ns:([^:\[\]]*)]/g, function (a, b) {
            var r = o[b];
            return typeof r === 'string' ? r : a;
        });
    };
}

var html = '<div>[ns:title]<h3>[ns:time]</h3><p>[ns:content]</p></div>';
var object = {title: "my title", time: "12h00m", content:"blablabla"}
supplanted = html.supplant(object);
//supplanted returns:
//<div>my title<h3>12h00m</h3><p>blablabla</p></div>
```

New regexp: `\[ns:([^:\[\]]*)]`.

First a `[` (special character while it is the literal `[` here, so needs to be escaped).

Then `ns:`.

After that any amount of any characters that does not contain a `[`, `]` or `:`:

```
(     // start group
[^    // none of following
:\[\] // : [ ]
]*    // any amount
)     // end group
```

Lastly a `]`.

Comment: thank you, i had to accept jensgram, as she was 2 minutes quicker. but thanks, really