# html jquery form checkbox

Tags: jquery, html

HTML:

```
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="lit" value="literary"><span class="checkdata">&nbsp;Literary Event&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="art" value="art"><span class="checkdata">&nbsp;Art Event&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cul" value="cultural"><span class="checkdata">&nbsp;Cultural Event&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
</td>
```

Script:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        if ("input:checked") {
            $(".checkdata").css("color", "#F0F0F0");
        }
    });
</script>
```

What I'm trying to do here is to check, if the user has checked the checkbox. If so, the `span class="checkdata"` should turn grey. It does not happen though.

Comment: [if checkbox is checked, do this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243554/if-checkbox-is-checked-do-this).

Comment: why is he using <code>this.checked</code> instead of <code>$(this).checked</code> ?

Comment: @anubhavgupta, in his post he links to a pretty great writeup.
Bottom line is, there's no real need to encapsulate "this" into a jquery object, as it only creates overhead (=slower) and isn't needed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
        if ($(this).prop('checked'))
        {
            $(this).next(".checkdata").css("color", "#F0F0F0");
        }
        else
            $(this).next(".checkdata").css("color", "#000000");

        });
    });
});
```

Test fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GQ4FY/1/

Comment: could you tell me why the in the link in the abve comment, the person has used this.checked instead of $(this).checked ?

Comment: You can replace the line `$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){` to 
`$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function()`
This is the fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/GQ4FY/2/

Comment: @anubhavgupta Why not Anubhav In short `this is the DOM object, whereas $(this) is the jQuery wrapper around same.` but for more info you can read from here http://forum.jquery.com/topic/difference-between-this-and-this-and-when-i-should-use-which and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633270/difference-between-this-and-this-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(function(){

    if($("input").is(':checked')){
        $(".checkdata").css("color", "#F0F0F0");
    }

});
```

Comment: This will apply the css to all spans irrespective of whether they are checked or not

Answer (score 0):

If you want to toggle the css when the checkbox value is changed, try this:

```
$(function () {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
        var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");
        if (isChecked) {
            $(".checkdata").css("color", "#F0F0F0");

        } else {
            $(".checkdata").css("color", "#000000");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function (){
var perform = {
   true : {'color' : 'green'},
   false: {'color' : 'red'}
 }, chk = $(this);

 $(".checkdata").css(perform[chk.is(":checked")]);

});
```

Prevent if statements :) Polymorphism.

Comment: That book changed my life.

Answer (score 0):

write your script as

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
        $(this).next('.checkdata').css('color', this.checked ? '#F0F0F0' : '#000000');
    });
});
```