# Hover effect like facebook

Tags: css, hover

I do create  a `<li>` like this.

```
<li>
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" id="form_friend_<?php echo $value; ?>" name="form[friend][]" />
<img id="img_friend_<?php echo $value; ?>" src="">
<label for="form_friend_<?php echo $value;?>" ><?php echo $label;?></label>
</li>
```

How can I do the hover effect for each friend like facebook does it?

Everywhere in the cell, e.g. Allen Yee, I can activate him to send him a request. How can I realize it with my `<li>`?

[image]

**Update**

in head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for( var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++ ) {
lis[i].onclick = function() {

    var c = this.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

    if ( c.checked )
        c.checked = false;
    else
        c.checked = true;
};
}
<script>
```

in body:

```
<li >
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="form_friend_1" name="form[friend][]" />
  <img id="img_friend_1" src="">    <label for="form_friend_1" >My name</label>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want all the content inside the `li` to trigger the `checkbox` to be selected, You should put all the content inside the `label` element.

```php
<li>
    <label for="form_friend_<?php echo $value;?>" >
        <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" id="form_friend_<?php echo $value; ?>" name="form[friend][]" />
        <img id="img_friend_<?php echo $value; ?>" src="">
        <?php echo $label;?>
    </label>
</li>
```

In this case you don't even need the `for` attribute on the `label`, because the `label` will apply to any form control (`input`, `select`, etc.) that is inside it.

If you want to change the style of the elements inside the `li` when it's hovered, you could use a [pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes) called `:hover`

For instance:

```
li:hover {
    background: #000;
}
```

It would change the background of the `li` element when it's hovered.

### **UPDATE**

As the framework you're using doesn't allow you to wrap all `li`'s content in the `label` element, I'd suggest you a solution with javascript.

Here's a simple example:

```
window.onload = function() {

    var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

    for( var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        lis[i].onclick = function(e) {

            e = e || window.event;
            var el = e.target || e.srcElement;

            if ( el.nodeName == 'INPUT' ) return;

            var c = this.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

            if ( c.checked ) {
                c.checked = false;
                this.style.background = 'white';
            } else {
                c.checked = true;
                this.style.background = 'blue';
            }

            return false;
        };
    }
}
```

The code above will take a list of all `li` elements that, when clicked, will get the first `input` tag inside of it and verify if it's checked, if so, it'll be unchecked, otherwise it will be checked. Also, it sets a background color for each case.

This script is simulating how an `input` of type `checkbox` would behave if it were wrapped in a `label` element.

### UPDATE 2

As you noted in your comment bellow, the `checkbox` isn't working properly. It's because there's occurring a [Event Bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html). There are also several [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+event+bubbling) in Stackoverflow with deep explanation of what it is.

I updated the snippet above in order to correct the `checkbox` functionality.

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wce45/5/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh, this is working, but I can't use your example. Because symfony2 renders first the input type checkbox then the label, so I can't put it inside label.

Comment: @Gunnar, is javascript an option?

Comment: Oh, the javascript I posted should be executed when the DOM has loaded. See edited answer, please. I corrected the code.

Comment: Crap, I could have seen this too! Works perfect! Thanks!!! Is it possible too, to set another background with javascript too? E.g. when I checked true then a blue background is coming up?

Comment: Sure it's. Just use the construction `Object.style.background = 'background-declaration';`. E.g.: `this.style.background = 'blue url(imgs/xyz.jpg) no-repeat';`. See edited answer on how to apply this to the javascript I posted.

Comment: Thanks again! Very cool and actually pretty easy. I really need to take a closer look to javascript!

Comment: hey, you answered this question. I found out, that I do have problem with that. I can not activate the checkbox itselft, so only the litte checkbox what is 16px x 16px. Everything else can be clicked and is activating the checkbox. Any idea?

Comment: Hi, @Gunnar. Yes, I know why and it's my bad, sorry. Take a look at the update answer, please.

Comment: Cool, now I can click the checkbox, image and background but not the text anymore. Crap, JavaScript is pretty cool, but I don't really get it. I am more in php and c programmer.

Comment: @Gunnar, could you please check the updated answer? Added a `return false` at the end of the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the hover effects both in css and JQuery. in css you can use '#idname:hover' or '.classname:hover'. In JQuery you can use:

```
$('selector that you select').hover(function(){
```

});

Comment: This sounds pretty interesting, but I don't get it really.

Comment: I assume you want to change the background of every box when hover. If you choose the CSS way, you can write: ".box:hover{background:#FFF;}". If you choose the JQuery way, you can write $('.box').hover(function(){$('.box).css('background-color','#FFF'});

Comment: No, I want to select the box. When I hover, the background is changing, but how can I select the field with a click?

Comment: You can do it with JQuery. The code will look like: $('.box').click(function)(){$(this).css('background-color','red');});. However this is a one-way ticket. If you click one of the boxes, it will change its background but when you click it again, it will remain same. If you want to toggle the background color on every click, you can use toggleclass() function of JQuery after defining a CSS class that changes background-color.

Comment: I want to toggle the background and to activate the checkbox.

Comment: than you should look that solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243554/if-checkbox-is-checked-do-this