# Uncheck checkboxes by checking other checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

So, I have six checkboxes, one of which is checked as default. The user is only allowed to check two checkboxes at a time, and this works fine. However, the if the default checkbox is checked, no other should be checked. This is what's giving me issues. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243554/if-checkbox-is-checked-do-this) and tried working from that.

So, I have 5 checkboxes with class `other` and one checkbox with id `default`. My problem is that I can't get it to check `default` when none of the others are checked.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLMcZ/) with the code — can you guys push me in the right direction?

Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" group="checkboxes" name="other" class="other" id="one">
  <label for="one">One</label><br />
<input type="checkbox"  group="checkboxes" name="other" class="other" id="two">
  <label for="two">Two</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" group="checkboxes" name="other" class="other" id="three">
  <label for="three">Three</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" group="checkboxes" name="other" class="other" id="four">
  <label for="four">Four</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" group="checkboxes" name="other" class="other" id="five">
  <label for="five">Five</label><br />
<input group="checkboxes" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="other" id="default">
  <label for="default">Default</label>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.other').change(function(){
    var c = this.checked ? false : true;
    $('#default').attr('checked', c);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxaids = "2";
    $(document).on('click', "input[type=checkbox]", function(){
        var bol = $("input:checked").length >= maxaids;
        $("input[type=checkbox]").not(":checked").attr("disabled",bol);
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 for the clear description and an interesting question indeed

Comment: `this.checked ? false : true;` is a bit excessive. Also, unless you're using an old version of jQuery; use `prop()` instead of `attr()`

Comment: Just curious what should happen if you uncheck 'Default'?

Comment: Actually, default is a hidden checkbox, just didn't want to overcomplicate things :) So it's not possible to uncheck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to check how many checkboxes with the class `other` are checked. If there aren't any, check the `default` checkbox:

```
$('#default').prop('checked', !$('.other').filter(':checked').length);
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLMcZ/15/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var maxaids = "2";
    $(document).on('click', "input[type=checkbox]", function () {
        if (this.id == "default") {
            var bol = $(this).is(":checked");
            $("input[type=checkbox]").not(this).attr("disabled", bol).attr("checked", false);
        } else {
            var bol = $("input:checked").length >= maxaids;
            $("input[type=checkbox]").not(":checked").attr("disabled", bol);
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kLMcZ/2/

***Update,***

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var maxaids = "2";
    $(document).on('click', "input[type=checkbox]", function () {
        if (this.id == "default") {
            var bol = $(this).is(":checked");
            $("input[type=checkbox]").not(this).attr("disabled", bol).attr("checked", false);
        } else {
            var bol = $("input:checked").length >= maxaids;
            $("input[type=checkbox]").not(":checked").attr("disabled", bol);
            if ($("input:checked").length == 0) {
                $("#default").click();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

See updated fiddle,
http://jsfiddle.net/kLMcZ/16/

Comment: Default does not get checked when all others are unchecked

Answer (score 0):

use `prop` to check the checkbox

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kenfly51/UUk99/)

```
$('.other').change(function(){
    var c = this.checked ? false : true;
    $('#default').attr('checked', c);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxaids = "2";
    $(document).on('click', "input[type=checkbox]", function(){

        var checkcount = $("input:checked").length;
        var bol = checkcount >= maxaids;
        $("input[type=checkbox]").not(":checked").attr("disabled",bol);
        if(checkcount == 0){
            console.log(checkcount);
            $('#default').prop('checked', true);

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var maxaids = "2";
$(document).on('click', "input[type=checkbox]", function(){

    var bol = $("input:checked").length >= maxaids;

    $("input[type=checkbox]").not(":checked").attr("disabled",bol);

    var checkCount = $('input[type=checkbox]')
                         .not('#default')
                         .filter(function(i, el){
                             return el.checked;
                         }).length;

    $('#default').prop('checked', checkCount > 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents: (the rest of your answer remains unchanged and is therefore not explicitly reported here)

```
$('.other').change(function(event){
    var boll = $("input:checked").length === 0;
    var c = this.checked ? false : true;
    $('#default').attr('checked', c);
//just check how many are checked, after you have applied the rest of your logic 
    if(boll) {    
//best to use 'prop' here, attr doesn't do the trick
        $('#default').prop('checked', true);}
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLMcZ/29/)